# Why am I getting 4 back when I should get an array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following in a variable called `store`

```
#<InitializeStore:0x007f83a39b72a0 
@inventory=[
  #<CreateStoreInventory:0x007f83a39b7228 @item="apples", @value=150>, 
  #<CreateStoreInventory:0x007f83a39b71d8 @item="bananas", @value=350>, 
  #<CreateStoreInventory:0x007f83a39b7188 @item="tissue paper", @value=450>, 
  #<CreateStoreInventory:0x007f83a39b7138 @item="soap", @value=850>
]>
```

Now when I try and do: `store.inventory` I should get an array. Instead I get everything inside the array spit out 4 times. This is not what I want. I want to be able to do store.inventory and get the array of objects.

I thought of assigning `store.inventory` to an inventory array, but it's already an array ...

Ideas?

Comment: How are you initializing this `store` variable?

Comment: `store = ClassName.new()`

Comment: Can you please post the relevant parts of that class?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your `InitializeStore` is implemented.

`store.inventory` is actually `store.inventory()`. It's not a field access, it is a method call.

Its result depends on that method (`inventory`) is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me:

```
require 'pp'

class InitializeStore
  attr_reader :inventory

  def initialize(arr)
    @inventory = arr
  end
end

class CreateStoreInventory
  def initialize(item, value)
    @item = item
    @value = value
  end
end

store_inventories = [
  CreateStoreInventory.new('apples', 150),
  CreateStoreInventory.new('bananas', 350),
  CreateStoreInventory.new('tissue paper', 450),
  CreateStoreInventory.new('soap', 850),
]

my_store = InitializeStore.new(store_inventories)
pp my_store.inventory

--output:--
[#<CreateStoreInventory:0x000001008423e8 @item="apples", @value=150>,
 #<CreateStoreInventory:0x00000100842398 @item="bananas", @value=350>,
 #<CreateStoreInventory:0x00000100842348 @item="tissue paper", @value=450>,
 #<CreateStoreInventory:0x00000100842258 @item="soap", @value=850>]
```

1) Oh, but you didn't post your code.  It's sort of hard to debug imaginary code.

2) Your class names are all wrong.  Class names should not have verbs in them, e.g. Initialize, Create.  Class names are things, which are nouns, e.g.:

```
require 'pp'

class Store
  attr_reader :inventory

  def initialize(arr)
    @inventory = arr
  end
end

class Product
  def initialize(name, price)
    @name = name
    @price = price
  end
end

products = [
  Product.new('apples', 150),
  Product.new('bananas', 350),
  Product.new('tissue paper', 450),
  Product.new('soap', 850),
]

my_store = Store.new(products)
pp my_store.inventory

--output:--

[#<Product:0x00000100842438 @name="apples", @price=150>,
 #<Product:0x000001008423e8 @name="bananas", @price=350>,
 #<Product:0x00000100842398 @name="tissue paper", @price=450>,
 #<Product:0x00000100842348 @name="soap", @price=850>]
```

3) `puts` <--> `p` <--> `pp`

`puts arr`: prints out a string representation of each element of the array--followed by a newline.  If the element is a string, and it already ends in a newline, puts doesn't add another newline.

`p arr`:  prints a string representation of the entire array, which just happens to look like an array you specify in your code, e.g. [1, 2, 3], with quotes around it.

`pp arr`: *pretty print* the array.  Like `p` but adds some formatting to make the output easier to read.